# Give all possible UID(s) same privilege as root user

Tags: permissions, sudo, docker

I have an ubuntu docker container where I pass the UID and GID from the host machine with the -u flag. But this also takes away the root privileges inside the container. But I would like to run everything inside the container as root. And the mounted volumes should create files with the UID en GID given with the -u flag.

For this case, it's possible to isolate containers with a user namespace.

But the downside of this solution is that it's only possible to do this with the start of the docker daemon. And only allows 1 users. Another big downside is that every remapping will get its own directory. So the images are not shared.

Any idea's on how to tackle this case?